# How to send document to elasticsearch from asp.net core API

Tags: c#, angular, elasticsearch, .net-core

My scenario is, I have angular UI when any error occurs it will send the details to the .net Core API from there I need to post the details to elastic search. right now the integration between angular and .net core is done. but I am not sure how will I post the document/data to elastic search. Everywhere when I search, they have shown the serilog way where I have to register the logger through program.cs and have to consume it through DI. the problem with that approach is that we will not be able to set the index dynamically. I want to assign a set of properties like index, method and other to make it easier to look through. Is there a API post call would be fine with the payload or anything else I need to do?. I will highly appreciate if anyone point me to some samples or blogs.

Comment: What are you trying to do? Logging to ELK and you just need to put some data to Elastic Search ?

Comment: Yes, I am trying to put logging information/document in elasticsearch

Comment: You can use elastic client for .net core [Elastic Client](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/net-api/current/introduction.html)

Answer (score 0):

This repository contains sample code for a .NET Core WebAPI application that demonstrates CRUD operations with Elasticsearch. You can find the code at https://github.com/workcontrolgit/ElasticSearchWebApi.

To understand how the application connects to Elasticsearch and see examples of CRUD operations, please review the following files:

Startup.cs: This file contains the configuration for the application's startup. Look for the Elasticsearch connection setup and initialization in this file. It should provide insights into how the application establishes a connection to Elasticsearch.

ProductController: The ProductController is a key component for CRUD operations. Examine this controller to see how it handles Create, Read, Update, and Delete operations related to products in Elasticsearch. This will give you a practical example of how Elasticsearch is integrated into the WebAPI.